# PHP's Float Precision Causing Problems With Small Numbers

Tags: php, numbers, floating-accuracy

I have an ojbect `$order` that has a member function `amount()` that adds up the sum of the line items (all floats) then returns the value (again, as a float).

```
var_dump(array(
    $order->amount() * 100.0, 
    intval($order->amount() * 100.0),
));
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7500
    [1] => 7499
)
```

The values of the line items are all under 1000 and never have more than 2 decimal points...

What is the best way to deal with decimal values in PHP, since the lack of precision is causing problems for me...

EDIT: To better illustrate:

```
echo "Addition: " . intval((172.45 - 72.45 - 25.0) * 100);
```

Result:

```
Addition: 7499
```

Comment: As stated above, everything is a float, no strings, no ints (except for that intval() )

Comment: This is why we don't use floats in finance.

Comment: There seems to be plenty of discussion on this topic if you search around. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662138/if-dealing-with-money-in-a-float-is-bad-then-why-does-money-format-do-it OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081988/php-mysql-best-money-operations-storing-practices

Comment: What's the alternative in PHP? There is no decimal type in PHP that keeps its precision...

Comment: @ian: do everything in cents instead of dollars. That eliminates having to drag around 2 decimal places.

Comment: I guess I'll have to do that, but this still leaves the problem of applying taxes, since I'll be multiplying against floats...

The solution I've opted for right now is to round($var, 2) after every arithmetic operation. Since I never use large numbers or very small numbers, this shouldn't be a problem.